# Find an n such that the equation $x^2+x=0$ in mod n has 4 solutions

Tags: abstract-algebra

So this is my question and I also have to do it so it has 8 solutions, my problem is that I don't really understand how to approach the problem at all.  Any type of help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: You must be at McGill in Prof. Goren's course ;)

Comment: His course notes but not his class!  My issue is I don't even understand it.  If I have for example that n=5, then would I have 2 solutions which are 4 and 5, because 16+4=20 which is congruent to 0, and then 25+5=30 which is also congruent to 0, is this the right idea?

Comment: Yes, I think you understand the problem correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: try to show that if $n$ is a product of $r$ distinct primes, then $x^2+x=0$ has $2^r$ solutions mod $n$.

Comment: sorry for basically writing what you had, but I really liked the problem and I had already started.

Comment: Dear @Jorge: No need to apologize! Questions belong to everybody. +1 to your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\dots p_k^{\alpha_2}
$

let $j$ be a solution, then $n$ divides $j(j+1)$, since these numbers are relatively prime, we must send all of the factors of $p$ in $n$ to either one of these numbers. So basically for each prime $p$ in $n$ we need to "select" whether $j$ or $j+1$ is going to be divisible by $p$

So each "selection" is going to give us a system of modular equations by the chinese remainder theorem.

$x\equiv s_1 \bmod p_1^{\alpha_1}$

$x\equiv s_2 \bmod p_2^{\alpha_2}$

$x\equiv s_k\bmod  p_k^{\alpha_k}$

Where $s_i$ is either $0$ or $-1$ (0 if that prime goes to $j$ and $-1$ if it goes to $j+1$). By the chinese remainder theorem each of these systems of modular equations has exactly one solution mod $n$

since there are $k$ primes and each prime must be sent to either $j$ or $j+1$ there are $2^k$ assignations and each one gives a unique solution.

Since we want $4$ solutions the answer is those numbers which have exactly two distinct prime numbers in their canonical factorization.